# Modulation ideas for old and long analog bus cabling

Tags: modulation, digital-communications

Need some feedback on techniques to make an old analog bus work with bidirectional data(half duplex is fine) at speeds upto 256kbps

The cable itself is a shielded twisted pair with a nominal impedance of about 50 Ohms. It's wired to various points in large buildings in anyway the installer felt was optimal (this includes daisy chaining, branching off into a star at a daisy-chained node etc). I believe it was used to pass audio and/or very low bit rate security data up to 500meters in length

Some of things I considered include:
1. A variant of 10Base2 at a lower data rate. The manchester encoding and csma/c(d/a) shouldn't be too hard to implement but the uncontrolled bus cabling worries me. At 256kbps(kHz) and some controlled slew rate the reflections and signal integrity shouldn't be too bad?
2. Restricting bandwidth to 40kHz or even 20kHz and increase bits/symbol by using QAM. This is not my preference because of the complexity of implementation unless if I can find a single chip SoC. Maybe there are bits and pieces of the old school v92 soft modem libraries I can re-purpose
3. Adapt Power line Communication techniques like G3-PLC

There is not much I can do to change the cabling as it's an existing installation. There won't be anything else on it, if it helps with reflections I can terminate it at each and every node. These cables are by and large interference free because of the shielding and differential signaling

Any thoughts/stories that you can share are most welcome. Thank you.

EDIT: The solution is not specific to one site, the wiring is different in each site and there about two dozen sites all up.

EDIT: There can be between 12 to 15 nodes on each bus

Comment: I think you need more information. Can you hook a 50ohm signal generator and drive e.g. a 250kHz square wave to see what kind of reflections you get? This cable might be lossy enough that the grody topology doesn’t really hurt.

Comment: I will be on site in 2 weeks so will be able to do more tests then but for now all I have is that the resistance is about 18 ohms for every 100 meter stretch of the cable. Reported by a field technician.

Comment: 50 ohms is a very low characteristic impedance for twisted pair, closer to 100 ohms is more likely...

Comment: OFDM is the magic bullet for squeezing high data rates through low symbol rates on a multipathy (stub reflections) medium. Whether or not you can leverage ADSL, or need to roll your own, is another matter.

Comment: OFDM is part of the PLC spec. If going the route of complex modulation, I feel like a 20khz band limited QAM will be relatively easier than OFDM?

Comment: Do you have access to the places where star connections have been made? It might be necessary to insert passive or active bridges there in order to control reflections. One thought that occurs to me is [AMI coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_AMI_code) used in digital telephony services such as T1 and E1 -- relatively easy to generate and decode (chips are available), and designed specifically for the STP cable that you're working with. It will require some creativity to do duplex over a single pair, however.

Comment: Another thought is the [2B1Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2B1Q) coding used in ISDN and similar services over UTP cable. Again, designed to be robust, even with questionable cable quality.

Comment: What is your budget for each endpoint? and what is the topology MIMO shared bus? CDMA ?

Comment: @BobJacobsen is this a Grody? https://us.v-cdn.net/5021068/uploads/editor/02/kzc1urxxjg68.jpg

Comment: @user183368  what is max range?  18ohms/100 meters sounds like a bit more than a AWG24 pair

Comment: @Tony Stewart Bus topology is a single pair of shielded twisted pair in combination of daisy-chaining  and star connections. The max range is about 500meters, I was told. This is the longest distance between any two nodes. The total bus length could be higher because of star-connection at some node points. The budget at each end point is something that's flexible but we are not intending to do full telecom grade rack of equipment if you get my drift.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for the suggestions, they seem similar to Manchester coding with bit stuffing. The availability of chips is a big plus though. Any suggestions on that front? I don't have access to any of the wiring have to work with what's already there unfortunately. Only the endpoints are accessible on a wall plate.

Comment: @user183368  so is it Half-D CDMA to hub? or any to any? Also how many nodes will be connected?

Comment: Back when I was designing T1 and E1 terminal equipment in the 1990s, we tended to use products from Dallas Semiconductor (now part of Maxim), but I'm not really familiar with what the current offerings might be.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I see what you mean. It's any to any half duplex with a simple CSMA/CA style signaling to minimize contention. 12 to 15 nodes.

Comment: @user183368 unfortunately unless each link memorizes the equalization from training for the signals from 0.1M to 1MHz it will be impossible.  Forget DS1/E1 with stubs  MIMO Modems and G3 Modems are MIMO but requires training to each point  1km maybe possible with 0.5Mbps.  EQ must be equalized in DSP. THis is a wired MESH and I dont have a lisp.

Comment: even though the network may resemble a tree the point to multipoint EQ is different for each Node, Hence the bandwidth must be split into cacscaded ~4KHz bands and multiplied by hundreds with DSP EQ training for each sub-band just like 56k modems or scaled up for BB cable modems except mutliple end-points each require separate coefficients. Talk to someone like Devolo for  serial to MIMO any to any network solution on CAT3

Comment: @mkeith  How many null Return loss frequencies would you expect with dozens of stubs on 0.5km? say up to 1MHz with a 1/4 wave= 37m Its a mess. WHich is why I think G3-PLC type with any to any training in memory is hard bt possible in theory. ODFM is the only way to get speed on secure wired connections but I would start to think about more secure WiFi

Comment: I  did point to multipoint DS1 in '79~83 to 100 nodes for -40~40'C and designed network tests for BER and  TDM sync and line buildout sync and that was easy. But point to multipoint demands a controlled impedance and short stubs in a bus, or a loop or a tree to Host.

Comment: again ask someone like Devolo if point to multipoint CAT 3 bus-tree will work for < $100 /node using a G3-PLC up to 0.5km  even 500KHz has 1/4 wave nulls at 300m

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I still think band limiting to 20kHz with about 7 bits/symbol + some FEC will do the trick. v92 had to put with **** cables and needed to combat interference. The big downside of these cable installations is the topology so if they can pass audio with high fidelity, there is a good chance a band-limited modulation will work.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, I didn't read the question carefully before commenting. Deleted my comment now.

Comment: What are your min speed requirements?  besides speeds upto 256kbps That determines everything

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Except for making it work with existing cabling and about 12 to 15 nodes, not much else. I am still waiting to hear more about the type of data that is sent over the link, if I can squeeze in some kind of compression that will relax the requirements.

Comment: I meant minimum speed.. like 56kbd is ok? worst case?

Comment: I suppose 56k as a fallback to communicate essential errors will work. What do you have in mind?

Comment: What's wrong with MU-MIMO-WiFi with twofish encryption in an embedded box.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 classic case of "Client Wisdom" imposed on Engineers

Comment: Then better to educate them on Bruce Schneirer's "two fish" which shud have been the winner of AES2000 but came in 2nd probably because the NSA had reasons, it was too good. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish "Twofish isn't even remotely broken" and is free open source

Comment: For the kind of data rates and distances, I would probably just use sub-Ghz RF transceivers with built-in AES encryption. I'll present all options to the client once I get a chance to do some testing on the cables.

Comment: If security is key, they should get an audit from Counterpane, they probably have worse issues that mitigate a wired solution.

Comment: I don't think security is the issue though. It's "Clients wisdom" about Availability of Wireless solutions because industrial RF is the same as consumer grade Wifi. Sigh.

Comment: Not so higher power units are avail , which I got that boosted my signal 30dB  https://amplifi.com/customer-service.html has a way to model path loss with a 2D drawing of wood, steel etc and there are Wifi extenders and Repeater protocols

Comment: Sorry, I was being sarcastic about client's thinking

Comment: mind you I recall using IBM's wifi free in a next door parking lot in San Jose. when I had no other means while waiting for a meeting. Open Wifi, just like Bruce had at one time. and 2 NATs makes it secure

Comment: This is probably an old Honeywell fire-alarm protocol. What speedup must you achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIth powerline modems it is possible to get 500Mbps, 300 meters in point to point but this requires equalization training for each point to a hub.

In P2P this would have to be trained for every combination of P2P and saved in the baseband modem which has to be done in parallel. So if anyone can be talking then you must have a low speed negotiating phase when idle.

300KHz with Er=4 has a full wave of 500m so using 10% of wavelength for  transmission line low reflection bandwidth leaves 30kHz of low reflection bandwidth at 110 Ohms =/-20% est. at HF limits which could support 250kbd easily and possibly 500k with EQ using ODFM.

But PSK,bi-ph has the best resilience (Steepest curve) for BER at  low SNR.  Compression factor depends on content if already compressed or not. FEC is desireable.

Consider R&D budget cost vs COTS modems,  I would be looking for  HD-PLC with Ethernet to a hub and loop back to get any to any using point to point PLC ( power line carrier) technology but without the AC power using choke grounds and RF caps to suppress AM ingress.

In other words a bus/tree  with MIMO Hub loopback to get P2P at max rate.

For low bit rates (TBD) simpler solutions exist...but  assumption was up to 256kbd.

Comment: Thanks for a very practical and considered response. I won't accept it as an answer just yet. Out of curiosity, what simpler solutions are out there for say sub-100kbps data rates?

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer since this put me in the right direction for further research. Thanks Tony.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/CAN_ISO11898-3_Network.png